# Wikipedia special features list

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am searching for the complete Wikipedia Feature list. I know there are some feature functions in Wikipedia like `Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day`.

Or is there a Media Wiki which describes the standard functions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is `Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day` a "feature function"?

Comment: ok...  i don`t know the exact term for that. i am searching for some different feature in wikipedia. As example. when i use this Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day it get the quote of the day, when i use Special:Random i get a andom article.
I am searching for the listing of all the wikipedia features.. hope that helps

Comment: I don't think a cross-wiki catalog of main page sections exists. Wikidata could in theory be used for that kind of thing but is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. This is what i was searching for, maybe others would find it useful. This lists all the speical properties

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page

Comment: Except `Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day` is not a special page, it's a normal MediaWiki page with [source code](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day&action=edit).